# Android Layout :- NestedScrollView + RecyclerView ----- Scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview

In my application I have a three textview which I want to be scroll-able and then below that I want to place a recyclerView. Then after I want that I can scroll these three textview separately and when scrolling the recyclerView the whole layout scrolls so that the textview are scrolled up and recyclerView items gets displayed. I have tried a variour options but failed.

One way through which I am able to achieve this is:-

```
<ScrollView

  <RelativeLayout

      NestedScrollView
         TextView1
         TextView2
         TextView3

      </NestedScrollView>

      <RecyclerView

      </RecyclerView>


   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But while using this layout if recyclerView has less items (say 50-60 ) then it works well otherwise the application hangs and have to force close application.

After so many different tries I think when I place recyclerView inside ScrollView (or NestedScrollView) then such behavior occurs.

Please help me with layout setup

Comment: Nested scrollview & RecuclerView are always a bad idea. I suggest you to use 2 different ViewHolder inside your RecyclerView: 1 for the TextView(1,2,3) and the other one for the elements actually inside the RecyclerView. In this way you need to check if the element is one of the first 3 and if so use the first ViewHolder, use the other ViewHolder instead

Comment: @LucaNicoletti As you said, I made two ViewHolder one for scroll view and other for Images. But In this I am not able to scroll textviews. When scrolled the whole recycler gets scrolled. So how to solve that.